# How do I do KNN test only on certain rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do KNN testing only on a few NA cells in my data frame. I want to fill these with data that is close to it, I have to get this to work for my testing data frame so I would like to not just set it. I want to fill the values in MasVnrArea

```
 StyleAndYrDF= trainDF.loc[:,['YearBuilt','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd']]
 Temp=trainDF.loc[230:234, ['MasVnrArea']]

  def fillIt(df,x):
         ID= findNearestHOF(df, x)
         return trainDF.loc[ID,'MasVnrArea']

 EstimatedMasVnr=Temp.apply(lambda x: fillIt(StyleAndYrDF,x) if (pd.isna(x.loc['MasVnrArea'])) else x.loc['MasVnrArea'])
```

I keep getting this error: KeyError: ('MasVnrArea', 'occurred at index MasVnrArea')

Answer (score 0):

You are applying across the wrong axis. This will fix your problem:

```
EstimatedMasVnr = Temp.apply(lambda x: fillIt(StyleAndYrDF,x) if (pd.isna(x.loc['MasVnrArea'])) else x.loc['MasVnrArea']
                          , axis=1)
```

Alternatively, I think this notation is cleaner:

```
EstimatedMasVnr = Temp.apply(lambda row: fillIt(StyleAndYrDF,row) 
                                         if (pd.isna(row['MasVnrArea'])) 
                                         else row['MasVnrArea']
                          , axis=1)
```

Comment: Okay, but now I have this error-> ValueError: ('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,) ', 'occurred at index 0', 'occurred at index 234')

Comment: do you have any suggestions? @Brandon

Comment: This error has to do with your `fillIt`/`findNearestHOF` function. You'll need to post that as well.